# Serving same servlet instance from different paths in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat

How can I instruct Tomcat to serve the same servlet instance from multiple paths?

E.g., given `example.com/old-address` and `example.com/new-address`, I would like to save the same servlet instance from these two addresses. I don't want to deploy the servlet two times. Is this possible with Tomcat standalone, without any Apache HTTP server/ reverse proxy URL rewriting?

Comment: Do you really care if it's the actual same instance of the servlet (i.e. the same object), or do you just want to use the same servlet class, in the same webapp? Because if it's the latter, just declare two servlet mappings in your webapp.

Comment: @JBNizet, I want to have the same instance, for two reasons: I don't want unnecessary memory consumption. And two or more servlet instances accessing the same database instance may cause conflicts in my particular case.

Comment: An instance of an object takes 16 bytes of memory, so I don't think that's a valid concern. And even if you just have one instance, it serves requests concurrently, so you are most probably **already** accessing the same database concurrently.

Answer (score 2):

There are many different levels on which to answer this question:

- The actual servlet *instance* (as in the sense of "instance of a class") is not your business: The application server itself decides how many instances of an object it wants to instantiate. (typically it's only 1 - per webapplication)
- If you deploy a webapplication on the root path of your server ("/"), you'll be able to map the URL `/old-address` and `/new-address` to the same servlet (again, don't worry about the *instance*. I assume though that you'd like to deploy an old-address.war and a new-address.war - in which case you'd run totally different web applications, that would be separated from each other by design.
- If you're migrating from one to the other application name, it's actually an advantage to configure proper redirects (permanent redirects, for that matter), so that sooner or later everyone has updated their bookmarks and links.

Following up on the comments:

A servlet must not keep any state in its instance. Requests are served concurrently and the state is coming in through the request and response objects. If you worry about concurrent access to some backend resources (as you state in a comment on the question): You already have a wrong implementation and have just been lucky to not have been bitten by it. Even a single servlet instance can handle thousands of concurrent requests (if the container accepts that many concurrent connections).

And memory consumption of a servlet *object* also doesn't matter (see my comment on that)

You're worrying about the wrong thing.

Comment: If I deploy the same servlet twice, it will require twice the memory of a single instance, right?

Comment: well, if you implemented your servlet the right way, that will make up a handful of bytes. If it has member variables that keep the current state of the request, it's wrong anyways: A servlet's state is only in request and response. As I said: You never know how many objects you end up with anyways. And don't worry about memory consumption unless you have measured that memory is your problem. In that case: Figure out what occupies the memory. My prediction is that it won't be the servlet objects, but rather something else. Fix that, if you're running out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a servlet-mapping in your web.xml like this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>yourServletName</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/old-address</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>/new-address</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The url-pattern element can be repeated arbitrarily inside the servlet-mapping element.